# NodeJS: Node-Inspector blank screen

Tags: node.js

for no apparent reason Node-Inspector stopped working. Although there was a search bar, no tabs display. When I run my app I get this warning message: warn  - websocket connection invalid

Comment: Did you forget to start node with `--debug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled node-inspector: `npm install -g node-inspector` It updated a couple of the dependencies and everything worked again after that.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing that can cause this is if your default browser is not Chrome.  Trying to run node-inspector in Firefox gives a mostly white screen.